# "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile error" during an openmp code execution

Tags: c, openmp

I got the following error and the stack trace during the execution of the attached OpenMP code.

```
Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=00100401966
rax=00000000014EB6A0 rbx=00000000FFFFCC50 rcx=00000000FFE03C00
rdx=00000000FFFFCC50 rsi=000000018027FB40 rdi=00000000FFFFCC7A
r8 =00000006000280A0 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000040
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000180248C20 r13=00000000FFFFCC7B
r14=0000000000000000 r15=00000000FFFFCC7B
rbp=00000000FFFFCCD0 rsp=00000000FFFFCBE8
program=some_dir...\example.exe, pid 134, thread 
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B

0 [] example 134 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to example.exe.stackdump

Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFCCD0  00100401966 (0010040108B, 000FFFFCCD0, 0018004A816, 000FFFFCC7B)
000FFFFCCD0  000016E36A0 (000FFFFCCD0, 0018004A816, 000FFFFCC7B, 00000000020)
000FFFFCCD0  00000000001 (0018004A816, 000FFFFCC7B, 00000000020, FF0700010302FF00)
000FFFFCCD0  0010040108B (00000000020, FF0700010302FF00, 0018004A7AA, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCD0  0018004A816 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180048353 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180048404 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

I don't think there are compiler issues since the compiler works fine without OpenMP. I searched on online-forums where most of them had issues with dynamic allocation which didn't help me.

**I know this is a messy code but I believe that this error is something related to declaring no. of processors.** `Line 16: omp_set_num_threads();` might be throwing errors. Again, these are some insights with my limited experience. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<string.h>

# define n 1000

int main(){


    printf("\n Start of the program\n");
    //printf("\nA random number %f", rand());

    omp_set_num_threads(16);
    int max;

    int k;
    double M[n][n], L[n][n], temp, A[n][n];

    printf("\n1.\n");
    //Generating a random 'n x n' matrix
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            A[i][j] = 1 / (2*(n - i+1 - j+1 + 1.5));
        }   


    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    for (k = 0; k < n-1; k++) {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int i;
            temp = 0.0;

            //Finding max in 'k' column
            #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i)
                for (i = k; i < n; i++) {
                    if (A[i][k] > temp) {
                        #pragma omp critical
                            temp = A[i][k];
                            max = i;
                        }
                    }
            #pragma omp barrier


            //Swapping A matrix
            #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(temp)
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    temp = A[k][i];
                    A[k][i] = A[max][i];
                    A[max][i] = temp;
                }
            #pragma omp barrier
        }

            /* Swapping B matrix
            temp = B[k];
            B[k] = B[max];
            B[max] = temp;*/

            #pragma omp parallel
            {
                int i, j, m;
                temp = 0.0;
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i,j)
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                            if (i == j)
                                L[i][j] = 1.0;
                            else
                                L[i][j] = 0.0;
                        }
                #pragma omp barrier
                }

                //Creating and updating Multipliers, M
                #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i,j)
                    for (i = k+1; i < n; i++){
                        M[i][k] = A[i][k] / A[k][k];
                    }
                #pragma omp barrier

                //Updating A matrix
                #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i,j)
                    for (i = k + 1; i<n; i++)
                        for (j = k; j<n; j++){
                            A[i][j] = A[i][j] - M[i][k] * A[k][j];
                        }
                #pragma omp barrier

                //Updating L matrix
                #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i,j)
                    for (i = k+1;i<n; i++)
                        for (j = k; j<n; j++){
                            L[i][j] = L[i][j] + M[i][k] * L[k][j];
                        }
                #pragma omp barrier

                /* Updating B matrix
                #pragma omp for schedule(auto) private(i)
                    for (i = k+1; i<row; i++) {
                        B[i] = B[i] - M[i][k] * B[k];
                    }
                #pragma omp barrier*/  
            }

    }


    printf("\n\nExecution time: %.9f\n", omp_get_wtime() - start_time);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh ... since it gave you a stack trace ... why don't you share the trace with us?  At a minimum, post the error message at the top of the trace. Please also identify the line# in your code the trace points to.

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried removing all the parallel stuff and it works. Maybe something error with my OpenMP stuff. Meanwhile, I have added the stack trace which I have no idea about its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=00100401966`.

The culprit is probably `double M[1000][1000], L[1000][1000], temp, A[1000][1000]`.

The question is "why?".

Q: What compiler/compiler version are you using?  What OpenMP version?

POSSIBLE WORKAROUNDS:

Q: What happens if you decrease to `omp_set_num_threads(8)`?

Q: What happens if you decrease  to `#define n 250`?

Q: What happens if you allocate your arrays with [malloc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), instead of declaring them on the stack?